# What is the nature of Baze and Chirrut's relationship?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In *Rogue One,* we (briefly) meet the characters Chirrut Îmwe and Baze Malbus.  They are both Guardians of the Whills and have history, but the exact nature of their relationship isn't explicitly said on-screen.

I had a friend who thought they were brothers, but I know they're not related.  And while Disney never would have confirmed them being a couple, I heard offhand that the actor for Chirrut said that the character was gay.  Is there anything that hints at this being their relationship, or do they consider each other brothers?

Comment: I always interpreted them as being in a romantic relationship, with the directors being too concerned about domestic and international backlash (particularly from China, which still censors same-sex relationships in many films) to make it more explicit.

Comment: @Adamant That's what I was wondering; Disney does have a history there.  It's entirely possible.

Comment: *"his best friend and moral compass"* - so no, not lovers.

Comment: Baze and Chirrut's relationship is a spheroid region, 705m in diameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are friends (and former co-workers).

> “Like so many conversations with you,” Baze said, “we are now back
> where we started.”
>
> “You noticed that, did you?”
>
> “You’re very lucky **I’m your friend,** you know that?”
>
> <sub><sup>[Guardians of the Whills](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Whills)</sup></sub>

The [databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/baze-malbus) describes them as such.

> The harsh reality of his Imperial-occupied home world has hardened
> Baze Malbus into a pragmatic soldier and a crack shot with his heavy
> repeater cannon. **Baze has a bravado that provides a marked contrast to
> the spiritual centeredness of his best friend and moral compass,
> Chirrut Îmwe.**

---

Interestingly, the film's director was happy enough to leave them *[ambiguously gay](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AmbiguouslyGay)* in various interviews.

> **Q. *Chirrut and Baze. Is there any subtext there? Because their relationship is very interesting.***
>
> GE: [Smiling] *Yeah, I don't mind people reading into that. I think that's all good. Who knows? You'd have to speak to them.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: Are Chirrut and Baze Star Wars's first same-sex couple?](https://uk.movies.yahoo.com/rogue-one-are-chirrut-and-base-a-couple-143845191.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: I mean, this does not really contradict, and if anything supports,  my hypothesis that they wanted to write the characters as being gay without having to deal with the consequences of making it clear (mainly, slightly less eye-popping sums of money going into their own pockets and mean reviews from international censors and religious conservatives). Which less charitably inclined people might even characterize as "queerbaiting."

Comment: @Adamant - I would characterise this very clearly as queerbaiting. A general willingness to wink at interviewers who ask if they're gay and a very firm description in the canon as anything but.